# React isn't waiting for Promise

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

I want setTickets to wait for the getTickets function to get the data... but it doesn't.  i tried using async await and by making setTicket(getSavedTickets()) my function.  How can I fix this?

Console logs show everything running before the DB has a chance to respond, at most, 2 seconds later.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import getSavedTickets from './getTickets';

function SubmissionForm () {
  const [tickets, setTickets] = useState('')

  useEffect (() => {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
      const myPromise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        res(getSavedTickets());
      }).then((response) => {
        setTickets(response);
      })
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {!tickets ? [] : tickets.map((tickets) => {
        return <li key={tickets.id}>
          From: {tickets.afrom} Subject: {tickets.asubject} Body: {tickets.abody}
        </li>
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SubmissionForm;
```

This is the function its importing.  I've also tried setting this to return a promise but of course it had no effect.

```
function getSavedTickets() {
  if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
    fetch(`http://${myIP}:3001/ticketCheck`, {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',},
      body: JSON.stringify({"user": [{username: document.cookie.split('=')[1]}]})
    })
    .then(response => response.json(),
    error => console.log(error),
    )
    .then(response => {
      return response.dbRes;
    })
  }
}

export default getSavedTickets;
```

idk what to do.  Every time I run into async issues in JavaScript the syntax or functionality makes it an extremely toxic couple of hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getSavedTickets is itself a promise, you don't need to create a new promise in the useEffect, just do something like

```js
useEffect (() => {
  if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
    getSavedTickets().then((response) => setTickets(response))
  }
}, []);
```

edit: looks like getSavedTickets also needs to be updated to return said promise:

```js
async function getSavedTickets() {
  if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
     return fetch(`http://${myIP}:3001/ticketCheck`, {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',},
      body: JSON.stringify({"user": [{username: document.cookie.split('=')[1]}]})
    })
    .then(response => response.json(),
    error => console.log(error),
    )
    .then(response => {
      return response.dbRes;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the correct solution but sadly 'then' is not defined.

getSavedTickets typeof // function
getSavedTickets console.log // the function I want

I'm not sure if you meant to edit

Comment: I updated the answer, but It would have not had .then defined when the cookie length was > 0, so, by making it an `async` function, it will always have a `.then`

Comment: oh I think you were typing an answer when I was typing the question lol.  Let me try it

Comment: See next comment for the solution if anyone is following this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was not waiting because async needed to be added to get saved tickets.  using .then instead of await.  Fetch returns a promise to the async function needed return next to fetch.  That let the async function getSavedTickets return a promise.  It fulfilled the .then in the main file with useEffect in it.

Not returning a promise and making the initially function Async was throwing me off.  Having those 2 issues to work out instead of one.

getSavedTickets

```
import { myIP } from './serverip';

async function getSavedTickets() {
  return fetch(`http://${myIP}:3001/ticketCheck`, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',},
    body: JSON.stringify({"user": [{username: document.cookie.split('=')[1]}]})
  })
  .then(response => response.json(),
  error => console.log(error),
  )
  .then(response => {
    return response.dbRes;
  })
}

export default getSavedTickets;
```

main file

```
  useEffect (() => {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
      getSavedTickets().then((response) => setTickets(response));
    }
  }, []);
```